# Accessing items in a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to access the only the keys of a dictionary within a list that contains integers and strings. Here is an example of the what that list looks like:

```
list =[
101, a, e, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
202, b, f, {'c': 2, 'd': 3}, 
303, c, g, {'e': 3, 'b': 4}, 
404, d, h, {'g': 2, 'h': 4}, 
505, d, i, {'i': 3, 'j': 4}
]
```

I'm able  to access each element of the list but not sure how to access the dictionaries of each item.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: It's not good idea to use ```list``` as name

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use builtin keywords of the language like `list` for variables, it can cause very nasty bugs in your code. To get the keys of the dictionaries, loop through the list and check if the current value is a dictionary, for example:

```
l = [
101, 'a', 'e', {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
202, 'b', 'f', {'c': 2, 'd': 3}, 
303, 'c', 'g', {'e': 3, 'b': 4}, 
404, 'd', 'h', {'g': 2, 'h': 4}, 
505, 'd', 'i', {'i': 3, 'j': 4}
]

keys = [ 
  list(d.keys()) for d in l if isinstance(d,dict)
]

print(keys)
>>> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'b'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j']]
```

Comment: `list` is not a reserved keyword (not in `keyword.kwlist`) it's not syntactically possible to assign to a keyword in python 3 (e.g. try `True = 'a'`). list is a builtin and it's best practise to shadow it

Comment: @Chris_Rands u r right! That's what I meant.

Comment: also just `[list(d) for d in l if isinstance(d, dict)]`

Comment: i prefer `list(d.keys())` , it's more verbose but easier to read than `list(d)`.